# How can I specify to lvconvert which mirror leg to drop when specifying the physical volume is ambiguous?

Tags: lvm

I have managed to end up with an LV with the following mirror setup (output from `lvs -a -o name,devices,lv_attr`):

```
  rawphotos                     rawphotos_mimage_0(0),rawphotos_mimage_1(0),rawphotos_mimage_2(0) mwi-ao
  [rawphotos_mimage_0]          /dev/sdb1(8741)                                                   iwi-ao
  [rawphotos_mimage_0]          /dev/sdc1(30743)                                                  iwi-ao
  [rawphotos_mimage_1]          /dev/sdc1(32081)                                                  iwi-ao
  [rawphotos_mimage_2]          /dev/sdb3(17343)                                                  iwi-ao
  [rawphotos_mimage_2]          /dev/sdb3(16062)                                                  iwi-ao
  [rawphotos_mlog]              /dev/sdc1(13)                                                     lwa-ao
```

I would like to drop `[rawphotos_mimage_0]` but the only way I see to control which image to drop is to use the `[PhysicalVolume[Path][:PE[-PE]]...]` argument to `lvconvert -m1`.

To drop `mimage_0` I need to supply both `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1` as these physical volume arguments, but then it also considers `mimage_1` as valid for dropping and chooses that instead. I also tried appending `:...` to specify the correct PEs to drop but this didn't help.

I can't find a dry-run option for `lvconvert` so I've found it difficult to experiment with this.

Is there any way I can make sure that `lvconvert` or some other LVM command choose `mimage_0` for dropping?

EDIT:

Note that the difficulty here comes because `/dev/sdc1` is used in both `[rawphotos_mimage_0]` and `[rawphotos_mimage_1]` - I didn't mean to get into this situation but now I need to get out of it!

Comment: Can you add the `lv_attr` option to lvs?  `lvs -a -o name,devices,lv_attr`

Comment: Done - edited it into the post